# Excerpt preview

Tags: excerpt

Is there a possibility to preview a manually created excerpt?

I would like to add a picture or a link to my post's excerpt, but I don't want to test my manual excerpt on my live wordpress.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Preview the post instead of publishing it.

Comment: It shows me the post preview, but not the post's excerpt preview.

Comment: Yes come to think of it that would be the case as you are previewing the single post as opposed to the post as it may be seen on an archive page.

Comment: I don't get it :)
Do you advise to take excerpt's code, insert it in a new post's text tab and then take a preview?

Answer (score 0):

You could publish the post as private, so when you logged in the excerpt is showing on the archive page.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work in my case because I use "show full post" on archive pages. But I will try your way, thank you!